# Why don't open-iconic icons show up when setting @font-face in css file?

Tags: css, blazor, font-face

I'm using the open-iconic library that comes with the default Blazor template in Visual Studio.
It's referenced in the css file `@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');`

I added some custom ttf fonts to my root folder. When referencing them in the css file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ALittlePot;
    src: url('../fonts/ALittlePot.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

then the open-iconic icons disappear. I even tried removing the content and just putting `@font-face { }` the same thing happened. It obviously has something to do with using `@font-Face`.

I tried adding my font using `@import url('../fonts/ALittlePot.ttf');` but then the font didn't render.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The console says `illegal Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character` on the @ symbol?

Comment: @horseman1210 there are no errors in the console at all so no. It _is_ loading the font. There doesn't seem to be any issues with the font, it just blocks the open-iconic icons from appearing.

Comment: Ok. I had a similar problem then came across your question. My issue was loading fonts from a Razor Library where you have to specify the `_content/{namespace}.` I have been using icons from open-iconic as default and are fine, sorry can't help.